# Finding nearest point feature in different layer, from start point of line feature

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-expression

I have two layers:

- `cables` (LineString), with attribute `lightpost_id`
- `lightposts` (Point), with attribute `id`

For every cable I want to set the `lightpost_id` to to the value of `id` of the lightpost point, which is closest to *the first vertex* (ie starting point) of the cable. I am trying to do this with the Field Calculator.

I know how to get the starting point of each cable:

```
start_point($geometry)
```

and for each cable I know how to get the id of the nearest lightpost, ie nearest to any point on the line.

```
overlay_nearest('cables',"id")
```

But I cant figure out how to combine the two, or to find the result in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

It will be very complex with MultiLineString geometry because one feature can represent many lines that have a start point. First I suggest you to convert your multi part layer to single part, this can be done with the [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) tool, then you can open the field calculator in the Line layer and calculate a new field with this expression:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='Lightposts',
    expression:="id",
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    order_by:=distance(
        start_point(geometry(@parent)),
        $geometry
    )
)[0]
```

replace every `Lightposts` lightpost layer id.

Comment: Thanks. But I think you misread my question. I want to set an attribute on the `cable` layer, not on the `lightpost` layer.

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer

Comment: @mayo, when using this expression for similar output (Z value of the point measured closest to the 0 vertex of line feature) the resulting z value is same across all the linear features. What do I do wrong? Expression below:    
'x: '||round($x_at(0),3)    
||    
' y: '||round($y_at(0),3)    
||    
' z: '||    
aggregate(    
   layer:='Messedatei',    
   aggregate:='array_agg',    
   expression:="field_4",    
   order_by:=distance($geometry,start_point(    
   geometry(@parent)))    
   )[0]

Comment: @SzymonPiotrJerzyCzwart, could you expand your question, I don't understand it very well. I suggest you to post your question as a [new](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) post. 