# Aggregate expression seems to be calculating the first value only

Tags: qgis, aggregate, qgsexpression

I have 2 vector layers: a point layer (named Messedatei, with 5 columns named field_1-5) and a line layer (each feature is build with only 2 vertex points).

I want to calculate the 'z value' of a point closest to the first vertex of each line so I'm using this expression proposed here ([Finding nearest point feature in different layer, from start point of line feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433879/finding-nearest-point-feature-in-different-layer-from-start-point-of-line-featu/)) in the field calculator:

```
aggregate(
            layer:='Messedatei',
            aggregate:='array_agg',
            expression:="field_4",
            order_by:=distance($geometry,start_point(
            geometry(@parent)))
            )[0]
```

Sadly, as a result, I'm getting the same 'z value' for every line feature, which shouldn't happen, because points I previously used as a vertices have different values in field_4.
When I do the calculation for other vertex point (thus using end_point instead of starting_point), I'm getting the same value, as to be seen on the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Are you working with multi geometries?

Comment: I'm wondering if the @parent functionality works in the order_by parameter.

Comment: @Mayo, both layers were processed with multiparts to singleparts, just to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the same result as you, even though the expression in the question looks like it should work.

With a point layer named Points and a line layer named Lines, and the z value in a field named 'z', I was able to get the expression to work with the tweak below.

It doesn't make any sense to me why adding `geometry(@parent)` into the expression field makes it suddenly work. It's worth noting that just adding the `@parent` feature (without `geometry()`) doesn't help, and neither does the (child) `$geometry`.

```
aggregate(
    layer:='Points',
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    expression:=array("z",geometry(@parent)),
    order_by:=distance($geometry,start_point(geometry(@parent)))
)[0][0]
```

Picture of dataset and z_val field on Lines layer using above expression, showing the correct result:

[image]

Comment: It works like charm, thanks